# Can't put a button in front of the textbox in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am editing code and I want to put a horizontal button in the text box.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class='btn btn-success' type="button" onclick="myFunction('fname')"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

But I am getting button a bit upper something like this [image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just bring out `label`:

```
<label for="fname">First Name</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off" >
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class ='btn btn-success' type="button" onclick="myFunction('fname')"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just move the button before the textbox and after the label

```
<div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <label for="fname">First Name</label>
          <button class ='btn btn-success' type="button" onclick="myFunction('fname')"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i></button>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off" >
      </div>
```

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/280547/

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="fname">First Name</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button class='btn btn-success' type="button" onclick="myFunction('fname')">test</button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you might have missed the 'code' button in the editor.

Comment: Hi there :) While this answer may solve the OP's problem, it would be great if it included an explanation of *why* it solves the OP's problem, so that the OP can have a solution *and* learn something from the experience. For example, you could say "note the change on the **n**th line, this is what makes the button show up in the right place"